# Why google map shows different marker on local server and on online?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have setup code for google map using V3. When I access the map on my local server, it gives perfect location and marker on correct place. But when I access it online with same address, it gives wrong location and incorrect marker place.

I get both of the address from the code too and placed on google map which shows correct place and marker locations.

why google map is not showing properly online while working perfect locally?

```
       var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;
    var myLatlng;
    var marker;
    function initialize() {
                                directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                 myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(" . $latitude . "," . $longitude . ");

                var myOptions = {
                  zoom: 15,
                  center: myLatlng,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\"map_canvas\"), myOptions);
                var contentString = \"<div style='width:190px;'>" . $address . "</div>\";
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
                });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
               marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: '" . (  $address  ) . "',

                });
               google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                  infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });
} 
function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  marker.setMap(null);
  var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:myLatlng,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Mind sharing some codes?

Comment: And the addresses that are returning different results?

Comment: Following is the address
Palmyra Road United Methodist Church 1600 PALMYRA ROAD Albany, GA 31701 US